# JavaScript non-parameterized function is still able to get arguments

Tags: javascript

Up to my knowledge, in most programming languages such as C#  and java, which are the common. The method or function need to have parameter to pass a variable.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(add(12,48));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    static int add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

However, If I try to call this method with out a parameter, I would get an error.

```
add();
```

On the other hand, if I call this method with an additional values I will received an error too.

```
add(12,16,52);
```

When it come up to the JavaScript, it's different. It is possible to pass variable to non-parameterized function.

```
function add() {

    var sum = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i]);
        sum += arguments[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Test

```
> add(15,25,5,40)
  15
  25
  5
  40
< 85
```

i'm wondering, "Is that an advantage?" or "Is it a kind of leak?".

If it's an advantage, so why are parameters still added in the JavaScript function?

If it's a leak, so how can I protract my JavaScript function from this leak?

Thanks a lot for all of you.

Comment: they are the actual values you are passing which is called arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can definitely be used as an **advantage**.

In JavaScript, all functions are inherently [variadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), meaning that they accept a variable amount of parameters.

You can't prevent this from occurring. What you *can* do is check the amount of arguments from within your function to differentiate between different invocations.

### ES5

In older versions of the language (pre-ES2015), you had to use the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) for this check. The *arguments* object is implicitly injected into all functions and **behaves similar to an array**, but **is not** an array (which prevents you to use Array methods directly on `arguments`). Note that using `arguments` is therefore generally frowned upon nowadays, since there are better alternatives.

```
function a() {
    console.log(arguments.length);
}
```

### ES2015+

From ES2015 and upward, you would usually use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to check the amount of arguments that were passed. One big advantage would be that rest parameters are actually real arrays and they are explicitly defined.

Since they are real arrays, you can call Array methods like `.map` directly on your rest parameters, which would require more effort with the older `arguments` approach.

```
function a(...args) {
    console.log(args.length);
}
```

### Function.length

Another helpful thing to know is that [`Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) returns the amount of actual parameters that were specified for the function. For example:

```
const three = (a, b, c) => {}
console.log(three.length); // 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object exists in every (legacy) function. This is by design. An empty parameter list is not an errer, even if named parameter are given. The value is the just `undefined`.

To protect your function you could check the length and throw an error.

```js
function add() {
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        throw new Error('got parameter, where no one expected')
    }
    console.log('add() called');
}

add();
add(0);
```

Comment: This ain't true anymore. Arrow-functions *(fat arrows)* don't have an `arguments` object; neither do they have a `this` object. Maybe they have one behind the scenes, but there's no way to access it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Java and C# are statically typed languages, JavaScript is dynamically typed - that's a fundamental difference between them, so it's why the function 'behaiour' is different.

On [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp) you can read, that:

> JavaScript functions have a built-in object called the arguments object.

So, definitely, it is not a leak.